# Is it possible to skip OAuth2 consent screen when using chrome.identity API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have been developing an extension, which is using the `chrome.identity` API (`chrome.identity.getAuthToken` method) in order to receive the OAuth2 token for signing up extension users via Google+.

I would like to push this extension in a company via Google Admin Console, but when `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` method is being called, our extension users are present with the "Identity API Scope Approval" screen - the consent screen, where users have to authorize extension's access to scopes we want access to.

I am aware, how process of getting OAuth2 access tokens works in general, and that user's approval is normally required in order to receive the OAuth2 token.

However, is it possible to automatically skip & authorize this OAuth2 consent screen **only** for users, whose extension was deployed via Google Admin Console?

I've found an interesting on Chromium Bugs list, where OP [states](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=345104):

> We are working on integrating Quickoffice for Chrome (which is a chrome extension) with the Drive Web UI. In order to handle OAuth we use chrome.identity, which works great.

and also the [following](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=345104#c6):

> since our extension is white listed as a first party app, we by pass the user content screen for the OAuth flow (which is what we want for the seamless integration with drive web ui).

I was not able to find any information, how to neither whitelist the extension as a first party app in order to prevent the consent screen from showing up, nor how to automatically authorize extension's access to those API scopes.

Any ideas?

Comment: First Party Apps means apps written by Google itself.  You are not Google.

Answer (score 1):

If you include `identity.email` in the manifest permissions, and it is a force-installed extension or app through the admin console, then you will be able to get the user's identity and also the auth token without user oauth prompt approval.

However this only allows you to get the user's identity, no extended permissions. Any extended permissions (such as gdrive access, etc) need an oauth prompt.

Comment: (Is this behaviour documented anywhere?)